# Disable some warnings in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers) and I'm currently testing it.
Seems great on many aspects, BUT...
... I get some warnings I'd like to get rid of, because they have no incidence and just tend to "hide" more useful warning hints.

Some variables/class instances used in all scripts are defined/instanciated in an "init.php" file.
This file is then included in all scripts where the variables/objects are needed.

=> this triggers warnings in the init.php file: *"Variable '$foo' is never used"*. But it IS used in scripts where init.php is included, so this warning brings no useful information to me.

=> this triggers warnings in the script including init.php: *"Variable '$foo' is undefined"*. It IS actually defined, but in the included file.

**Is there a way to tell Eclipse *"Ok, I know, you think it's not used (or not defined), but please, just don't tell me!"* ?**
In a comment with a specific syntax for instance?
Something comparable to javadoc for instance?
Or any other kind of meta-information intended to the editor?

Comment: you should be able to get rid of the undefined warning by putting phpdoc before using the variable. something like /** @var int $variable **/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @user10099 :

- Adding `/** @var int $variable **/` before using the variable removed the *"variable undefined"* warning.
- Adding the same before defining the variable (in the included file) also removed the *"variable never used"* warning.